# C++ struct tm & time_t

Tags: c++, c++11, time-t

I have an array of time here:

```
struct cl{
    unsigned char *buffer;
    time_t t = time(0);  
    struct tm * ct = localtime(&t);
};
```

and then:

```
cl sadi[10];
```

But for example I got `sadi[5]` at `21:58`, and when I got a `sadi[6]` at `21:59`.
Then I check again all my `sadi[].ct->tm_min` are `59`. What is the problem with that? Is that it can't hold the moment that you capture it, will it always update ? If so, how can I capture the moment of time and it not update like that.

Comment: Is that even valid C++? When did it become possible to initialize members of a struct like that?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Since C++11. You can have in-class member initialization.

Comment: like the answer bellow, that was my mistake, i shouldnt initialize a member with pointer like that in this case,

Comment: You can also use `std::chrono`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point. Sometimes C++ makes your life simpler. If you want to do calculation with dates, I recommend Howard Hinnants great libraries: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This line:

```
struct tm* ct = localtime(&t);
```

The problem is that the *pointer* that `localtime(&t)` returns is a *static* internal buffer. So it returns exactly the same pointer value (address) every time it is called. That means that all your array elements have pointers to the same `struct tm` object.

One solution is to make a *copy* of the data each time you call `localtime`:

```
struct cl {
    unsigned char* buffer;
    time_t t = time(0);  
    struct tm ct = *localtime(&t);
};
```

So now I declare `struct tm ct;` (not a pointer) and initialize it with the *dereferenced value* of the returned pointer `*localtime(&t)`.